# Получение блока XML по селектору

Tags: java, xml, api, xmlparser

Я использую **worldweatheronline API.**  Сервис отдает xml примерно в следующем виде:

```
   <hourly>
      <tempC>-3</tempC>
      <weatherDesc>rain</weatherDesc>
      <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
    </hourly>
    <hourly>
      <tempC>5</tempC>
      <weatherDesc>no</weatherDesc>
      <precipMM>0.1</precipMM>
    </hourly>
```

1. Могу ли я как-то получить все узлы `<hourly>` в которых `<tempC>` > 0 и  `<weatherDesc>` = rain?
2. Как исключить из ответа не интересующие меня узлы `<hourly>`?

У меня получается получить значения атрибута используя метод `getTextContent()`, но такой способ мне кажется плохим, потому что если нужно будет получить значения двух атрибутов - придется писать два селектора и дважды получать результат:

```
        private final String XPATH_PATTERN = "//hourly[tempC>0]";

        InputStream response = given().when().get(URL).asInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(response);
        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(XPATH_PATTERN);
        Object resuslt = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) resuslt;
        for(int i = 4; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getTextContent()); //возвращает нужные мне значения, но этот способ плох
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("tempC")); //возвращает null
        }
```

Как из оставшихся узлов `hourly` получить нужные атрибуты?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону XPATH, XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать примерно такой XPath: //hourly[tempC>0 and weatherDesc='rain']
См.: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp
https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath

Comment: Прошу прощения за  наглость. Я дополнил вопрос, буду рад если Вы взглянете еще раз

Comment: @PavelBobrov Используя XPath, Вы получаете список элементов `hourly`. Чтобы получить значения каждого элемента внутри `hourly`, можно привести `Node` к `Element` и вызвать у него метод `getElementsByTagName("tempC")`.   
Или, если Вам нужно только значение `tempC` в каждом элементе `hourly`, можно использовать: `//hourly[tempC>0]/tempC'

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что речь идет о `w3c.dom.Element` и выглядеть это должно примерно так: 
`NodeList nodes = (NodeList) resuslt;
                    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("tempC"));`

Спрашиваю потому что все ровно восвращается объект NodeList `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@1921ad94`

Я не силен в Java, извините

Comment: @PavelBobrov Почти так, только `getElementsByTagName("tempC")` возвращает список (NodeList) элементов с именем "tempC". У Вас, он, видимо, всегда будет иметь один Element внутри. Т.е. Вам надо вызвать `getElementsByTagName("tempC")`, проверить что он не пустой (на всякий случай) и потом взять 0 элемент из него и вызвать `getTextContent()`

Comment: Все действительно так, все работает. большое спасибо.